# FindElement in Selenium without using Xpath

Tags: java, selenium

I want do find the element  without using xpath, but I have another ul´s elements and "class=title" on my page. So, I cannot use Type or "class=title" either.

```
<div id="pai">
<div class="def">
    <div class="abc" >
        <p class=title>Title</p>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
```

I´m thinking about something like below, but I don´t know if it is the best practice:

```
WebElement um = driver.findElements(By.className("abc"));
WebElement dois = um.findElements(By.className("title"));
tamUl = dois.findElements(By.tagName("ul")).size();
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use Xpath? Why not CSS else?

Comment: That works, but it's better practice to just have your selector pick what you want, especially if `um` serves no other purpose here than to find `dois`. Css selector `.abc .title`. I'm not sure I understand why not use xpath, but css selectors tend to be a bit cleaner when you can use them if you're open to those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when you can't or not willing to use Xpath or CSS selectors, you want to get list of all needed elements present on the page. Then you choose (either empirically, by debugging or using conditionals) the index of the specific element to use. Following might be the case you want to try:

```
List <WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("title"));

if (elements.size() > 0) {
  elements.get(INDEX_OF_YOUR_ELEMENT).findElements(By.tagName("ul")).size();   
}
```

Pay attention to the difference between [findElement()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) and [findElements()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) methods. While findElement() returns only first element if multiple occurrences are found, at the same time it throws NoSuchElementException if nothing is found, where findElements() only returns empty list.

Comment: I didn´t undesrtand this "get(INDEX_OF_YOUR_ELEMENT)".
What element is that?

Comment: `public int areaTeste() {
  
  List <WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("title"));

  if (elements.size() > 0) {
    int tamArea = elements.get().findElements(By.tagName("li")).size(); 
    return tamArea; 
  }`

Comment: @CarolC, if you have 2 elements with class "title" on page, you'll get the list of size 2 with those elements. So it is up to you to choose what element of that list to use (you can access element in the list by index, 0 for the first element, 1 for the second etc). The order of elements on the page is preserved in the list.